# Proving positive definiteness for a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Let A be an $n\times p$ matrix with rank $p$. I want to prove that $X = A^TA$ is a positive definite matrix.

I know that for any symmetric matrix to be positive definite, all of its eigenvalues must be strictly positive.

So I need a way to show that $X$'s eigenvalues are all positive, or perhaps any other method to proof that $X$ is positive definite.

Comment: matrix $Z$ is positive definite if $x^TZx>0$ for any vector $x$ ... plug in $Z=A^TA$ and you'll find that you're looking at the norm of a vector $Ax$ which is always greater than zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested above by phdmba7of12, we consider the quadratic form

$$x^T X x = x^T (A^T A)x = (Ax)^T (Ax) = (Ax, Ax) = \lVert Ax \rVert^2 \geq 0.$$

Since $A$ has rank $p$, the only solution of $Ax = 0$ is the trivial solution. Hence,

$$x^T X x = 0 \iff x = 0.$$

Hence, we have varified the definition of positive definiteness.

Answer (score 0):

It is straightforward to show that $A^TA$ is positive semi-definite by showing $x^TA^TAx \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{p}$, therefore $A^TA$'s all eigenvalues are non-negative.

Now using the fact $\mathrm{rank}(A^TA) = \mathrm{rank}(A) = p$, hence as an order $p$ matrix, $A^TA$ is non-singular. Therefore $A^TA$ doesn't have zero eigenvalues.

Combining these two arguments together, we see that all eigenvalues of $A^TA$ are positive, thus $A^TA$ is positive definite.